# DataTables pagination differs between initial load and selecting number per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I'm struggling to get DataTables to display the same pagination behaviour on initial load as when a user selects a number of results per page.
When first rendered to screen it looks ok, with e.g. 25 results on the page, but on clicking another page number it goes from e.g.

```
"Showing 1 to 025 of 301 entries"
```

To:

```
Showing 26 to 301 of 301 entries
```

So rather than showing just the next 25 results on page 2 it's showing ALL those except the first 25. If I choose a number of rows per page from the drop down menu this behaviour corrects itself and I see the 25 results per page I'd expect.

I've had a good look around and for all I can tell the option that should sort this is e.g.:

```
pageLength: "25"
```

But I'm using this already. Please see JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly4qnfs5/4/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the quotes from `pageLength: 25` making it a number (and not a string)

https://jsfiddle.net/Ly4qnfs5/5/